# Cassandra: turn the paging off in Java

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

say i have the following CQL3 query:

```
QueryString = "SELECT id1, id2, link_type, visibility, data, time, version from keyspace.table where id1 = id1 and link_type = link_type and id2 **IN id2s** and time>= minTime and time<= maxTime ORDER BY time desc limit= rowLimit;"
```

1. If i implement it as a `Statement = new Statement (QueryString)` i get this error (because of the brackets in the id2s: a List):

> no viable alternative at input '[' (...and link_type = 123456789 and
>   [id2] IN...)

---> how should i convert the `List<Long> id2s` to a List without brackets but with parentheses : (item1, item2, item3)

2. If i implement the query as a PreparedStatement:

`PreparedStatement prepared = session.prepare(query);`

the first Error was resolved but i get another:

> Cannot page queries with both ORDER BY and a IN restriction on the
>   partition key; you must either remove the ORDER BY or the IN and sort
>   client side, or disable paging for this query

----> how should i turn the paging off with a Prepared Statement (i found only solutions with the simple statement : statement.setfetchSize() but not with Prepared Solution)

If i use a simple statement i get a problem with the Brackets/parentheses and if i use a prepared statement to solve the last, i get a problem with the paging.

Any idea ?

Comment: Why don't you set a very big number as the limit? By the way you do not achieve paging with this as you do not have an offset defined to select subsequent pages

Comment: I set 10000 as limit and i have the same problem. I get this only with the ordering by limit clause...

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. is there any way out ?, like we do 'paging off' in console ?

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can turn off cassandra paging by following code

```
Statement statement = new SimpleStatement(query);
statement.setFetchSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

And execute the statement.

```
session.execute(statement);
```

It should work fine